# nginx: log empty calls

Tags: nginx, log-files

Does nginx have an option to ignore health checks or buckets from load balancer against nodes?
There are thousands of entries like

> > 93.190.2.176 - - [24/Jul/2012:08:56:59 +0200] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"

in my access.log which are useless to me.

Thanks for a tip

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    access_log  off;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/r/listen

Comment: doesn't this turn off all the logs?!

Comment: If you have another `server` sections with relevant `server_name`, then it turns off only for requests those don't reach one. Did you read the first link above?

Comment: Note, that you can also have `server` section with `server_name '';` and `server_name *;`

Comment: yes, but i can not see if the ip or which server_name ist called. the log does not tell me. btw. i do not have a index file on this server, it's a blank page and only the health check is calling /

Comment: Again. Do you read the docs? `default_server` means that this `server` section will be chosen by default even if no data were sent.

Comment: In your case, according to log, it just opens connection and closes without any data.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) in your global `server` config file and turn it on only in selected locations.

Comment: No, the log is fine. However, the empty entries are useless. No chance to filter and leave them?

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure your health check to pull a particular url then you can turn off access logging for it specifically

```
location = /health.php {

 access_log     off;
 ...
}
```

Comment: That's probably a TCP, not HTTP, healthcheck (hence the 400 status code), and so there's no URL to match unfortunately.

Comment: @mgorven: That's why I said `if ... ` some LBs let you set a http health check.